# Eclipse how to change color of edited text

Tags: eclipse

I can't figure out where in Eclipse I can make the edit change to show a different color on the left side for a line that has been edited/changed (before saving the file).

This are is right behind the line numbers...when I make a line edit this small rectangle behind the line number changes now to light gray and I want a different color!

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

If you enable line numbers the lines you did modify will be marked with a different color: right click on the margin at the left of the editor window and select "Show line numbers"

Comment: Yes I have line numbers shown already...I want to change the BG color of modified lines from the light gray which I find hard to see to a brighter color such as yellow.

Comment: I see the current line in gray and you can change it from Window-Preferences under General->Editors->Text Editor->Apperence color option box -> Current line highlight the number will report in pink a marker to all lines you edited

Comment: That setting allows me to change the current line marker color across the width of the text line...that doesn't change the BG color of the line number rectangle when I edit a line.